# Is it possible to conditionally sum within a select statement?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 14, and I have a `running_cities` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."running_cities" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('running_cities_id_seq'::regclass),
  "city_id" int8,
  "user_id" int8,
  "completed_streets_count" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "region_id" int8,
  "country_id" int8,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
```

I have a materialized view that collects various stats/info for each User like this:

```sql
SELECT users.id,
  array_agg(running_cities.city_id) AS cities,
  COALESCE(rc.cities_count, 0) AS cities_count,
  users.completed_streets_count,
  array_agg(DISTINCT running_cities.country_id) AS countries,
  COALESCE(rc.countries_count, 0) AS countries_count,
  RANK() OVER(
    ORDER BY users.completed_streets_count DESC
  ) AS position,
  array_agg(DISTINCT running_cities.region_id) AS regions,
  COALESCE(rc.regions_count, 0) AS regions_count
FROM users
  INNER JOIN running_cities ON running_cities.user_id = users.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT running_cities.user_id,
      COUNT(*) cities_count,
      COUNT(DISTINCT region_id) regions_count,
      COUNT(DISTINCT country_id) countries_count
    FROM running_cities
    GROUP BY running_cities.user_id
  ) rc ON rc.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id,
  cities_count,
  countries_count,
  regions_count
```

An example of its output is:

```
id  cities  cities_count    completed_streets_count countries   countries_count position    regions regions_count
1   {187863,1690,1686,1649,2547,22505,1700,1693,1697,1717,2494} 11  273 {207}   1   1   {784,801,821}   1
```

My goal is to add some additional "completed street count" values to the materialized view that don't currently exist e.g. total completed streets for each city/region/country.
The single-user SQL queries for this are fairly simple:

```sql
SELECT completed_streets_count FROM running_cities WHERE user_id = 1 AND city_id = 1
SELECT SUM(completed_streets_count) FROM running_cities WHERE user_id = 1 AND region_id = 1
SELECT SUM(completed_streets_count) FROM running_cities WHERE user_id = 1 AND country_id = 1
```

To accomplish this for the entire materialized view, I *think* I'd like to change each of the 3 `array_agg` calls to something that will produce jsonb like `[{187863: 100}, {1690: 10}, {1686: 40}]` in the generalized formats of:

- `[{city_id: completed_streets_count}]`
- `[{region_id: completed_streets_count}]`
- `[{country_id: completed_streets_count}]`

I'm struggling quite a bit in trying to figure out how, exactly, `array_agg(running_cities.region_id) AS regions,` changes to make this possible.
My attempts so far with `jsonb_object_agg` have largely failed because I haven't gotten it to filter on the second conditional (`country_id` in this example):

```sql
jsonb_object_agg(
  DISTINCT running_cities.country_id,
  (SELECT SUM(completed_streets_count) FROM running_cities WHERE user_id = users.id AND country_id = running_cities.country_id)
) AS countries
```

This comes *so close*, but the values all end up being that User's total completed street count, not the isolated count for each `city_id`/`region_id`/`country_id`.

Is it possible to do a conditional `SUM` in a query like this?

Comment: Please replace the prose about your table with an actual `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. That's the one (workable) source of truth. Disclose your version of Postgres. Ideally, add a fiddle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your problem is confusion in irrelevant technology bloat, all that talk about JSON is irrelevant. Write a query as a relational query. You're going to have a lot of group by here. Learn to use WITH to divide your logic up. Turning the result into JSON is the last step.